# Remove attribute from ServletContext after timeout

Tags: java, jersey, servlet-3.0

I am implementing a web application backed up by java rest services (jersey).

Using javascript, I'm calling a service in localhost created by a third party application that the user has to install. That application calls a service for digitally signing PDF files in the same webapp, but that call doesn't have the session id that my page has, therefore I can't access session attributes.

To circumvent this, before calling the third party app, I use javascript to call a service in my webapp that creates an attribute in ServletContext, and later I access that attribute from the service used to sign PDF files.

If the call is successful, I can remove the attribute easily, but if some call has errors, the attribute could remain in the ServletContext indefinitely.

Is there some way to remove a ServletContext attribute after a timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain the flow more, have some sequence diagram or something?
Looks like a very convoluted implementation, from the description. ServletContext is application level data and storing session level information in it is bound to fail. Also what about more than one user using the application simultaneously. Also storing state on server goes against the principle of REST.